# Books/articles about étale cohomology of Grothendieck toposes

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, homology-cohomology, book-recommendation, topos-theory

Toposes were invented to define étale cohomology (and with that, prove the Weil conjecture). All this is written down in SGA4 and SGA$4\frac{1}{2}$.

However, it can be a bit overwhelming, to try to read these sources.

*Question:* Are there other resources with which one can learn the theory of (étale) cohomology of Grothendieck toposes?

Often recommended books in this context are Milne's *Etale cohomology*, Artin and Mazur's *Etale homotopy*, and Artin's lecture notes *Grothendieck topologies*, but all these sources don't directly discuss *toposes* as far as I can see. I'd like to see an introduction directly discussing toposes.

Comment: I think you’re asking for two different things. Are you interested in the development of cohomology for sheaves of modules on a Grothendieck site – the construction, the general properties? Or are you asking about the specific properties of the étale cohomology on schemes – say, the proper and smooth base change theorems, the six-functor formalism?

Comment: Both, if these things have to do with assigning cohomology groups to topoi. :-)

Comment: I think that the slides of “cohomology and topos” at http://www.oliviacaramello.com/Teaching/Teaching.htm are a decent starting point for both purposes. Regarding étale cohomology specifically, I learnt a little bit from Freitag and Kiehl, *Étale cohomology and the Weil Conjectures*, which is, while still difficult, probably more focused (though less complete) than SGA.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide whether you want to study etale cohomology or topos theory --- except for SGA 4, they are rather distinct topics. For example, SGA 4.5, which is Deligne's exposition of the prerequisites on etale cohomology needed for his proof of the last of the Weil conjectures doesn't mention them as far as I know. Etale cohomology was developed for its applications to algebraic geometry, and doesn't need any topos theory. Topos theory is part of logic and the foundations of mathematics.